# Hitting metal when hanging curtains

Tags: drywall, metal

I am hitting metal about an inch from the ceiling. I went back to the photos/videos of when they were doing construction and there seems to be a long metal piece (about 2 ft) running horizontally along one of the horizontal studs in the area I’m drilling. There doesn’t seem to be wires there (no outlets in the area or light switches) and definitely no plumbing. Curious to know what it could be for and if it might be okay to drill into.

Comment: Usually placement of metal plates/pieces are not done for the fun of it.  Mainly to stop us idiots from drilling/nailing into something we are not suppose to.  It could also be duct work.  If you could post a picture of the metal piece when house was being built it would help.

Comment: [Edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/235597/edit) your question and add a photo so we can see too.

Comment: A still picture grabbed from your video would be ideal, but at a minimum, please describe the strap (perforated? solid?) and its location (top plate? header?).